# Ax.dev does not do anything with search space constraints?

Tags: python

I found some articles online that mentioned Ax.dev's capability to cope with a constrained search space (e.g. dimension_x + dimension_y <= bound). However, I only experienced Ax.dev to ignore/violate all constraints. I have tried some different constraints on the Hartmann6d example. I assume Ax.dev models the constraints as soft constraints (not sure though, might as well be my coding skills...). So, my first question is: does Ax.dev `SearchSpace` use `parameter_constraints` as soft or hard constraint(s).

My second problem:

```
from ax import *
number of parameters
...
c0 = SumConstraint(parameters=[ some parameters ], bound= some boundary)
c1...
space = SearchSpace(parameters=[ parameters ], parameter_constraints=[c0, c1])
exp = SimpleExperiment(
    name='EXPERIMENT5',
    search_space=space,
    evaluation_function=black_box_function,
    objective_name='BLABLA',
    minimize=False,
    )
sobol = Models.SOBOL(exp.search_space)
for i in range(10):
    exp.new_trial(generator_run=sobol.gen(1))
    exp.trials[len(exp.trials) - 1].run()
```

returns

SearchSpaceExhausted: Rejection sampling error (specified maximum draws (100000) exhausted, without finding sufficiently many (1) candidates). This likely means that there are no new points left in the search space.

I have not been able to find useful information concerning this, despite all promising articles online stating ax.dev benefits (such as a constrained parameter space!) :(

Comment: Needs a MWE to comment on why you're getting `SearchSpaceExhausted` and if that's a symptom or a cause. See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

meta-comment: Probably a better place for GitHub issues (not much by way of Ax help/docs on stackoverflow to my knowledge, but their GitHub issues is rich and generally has a lot of developer/community support).

### Does Ax.dev SearchSpace use parameter_constraints as soft or hard constraint(s)?

I think parameter constraints are hard constraints (pretty sure that's the case at least for Sobol sampling, but I'm not sure about Bayesian models).

[Outcome constraints are soft penalties (constraints)](https://ax.dev/tutorials/multiobjective_optimization.html#Set-Objective-Thresholds-to-focus-candidate-generation-in-a-region-of-interest)

### SearchSpaceExhausted: Rejection sampling error

Search: https://github.com/facebook/Ax/issues?q=is%3Aissue+sort%3Aupdated-desc+specified+maximum+draws+is%3Aclosed

--> https://github.com/facebook/Ax/issues/694

--> https://github.com/facebook/Ax/issues/694#issuecomment-987353936

> Since it's on master, first I [install the latest version](https://ax.dev/docs/installation.html) in a conda environment:
>
> ```
> pip install 'git+https://github.com/facebook/Ax.git#egg=ax-platform'
> ```
>
> The relevant imports are:
>
> ```py
> from ax.modelbridge.generation_strategy import GenerationStrategy, GenerationStep
> from ax.modelbridge.registry import Models
> ```
>
> Then based on [1A. Manually configured generation strategy](https://ax.dev/tutorials/generation_strategy.html#1A.-Manually-configured-generation-strategy), I change the first `GenerationStep` `model_kwargs` from:
>
> ```py
> model_kwargs={"seed": 999}
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```py
> model_kwargs={
>     "seed": 999,
>     "fallback_to_sample_polytope": True,
> }
> ```
>
> With the full generation strategy (`gs`) given by:
>
> ```py
> gs = GenerationStrategy(
>     steps=[
>         # 1. Initialization step (does not require pre-existing data and is well-suited for 
>         # initial sampling of the search space)
>         GenerationStep(
>             model=Models.SOBOL,
>             num_trials=5,  # How many trials should be produced from this generation step
>             min_trials_observed=3, # How many trials need to be completed to move to next model
>             max_parallelism=5,  # Max parallelism for this step
>             model_kwargs={
>                 "seed": 999,
>                 "fallback_to_sample_polytope": True,
>             },  # Any kwargs you want passed into the model
>             model_gen_kwargs={},  # Any kwargs you want passed to `modelbridge.gen`
>         ),
>         # 2. Bayesian optimization step (requires data obtained from previous phase and learns
>         # from all data available at the time of each new candidate generation call)
>         GenerationStep(
>             model=Models.GPEI,
>             num_trials=-1,  # No limitation on how many trials should be produced from this step
>             max_parallelism=3,  # Parallelism limit for this step, often lower than for Sobol
>             # More on parallelism vs. required samples in BayesOpt:
>             # https://ax.dev/docs/bayesopt.html#tradeoff-between-parallelism-and-total-number-of-trials
>         ),
>     ]
> )
> ```
>
> Finally, in the case of this issue, and as mentioned:
>
> ```py
> AxClient(generation_strategy=gs)
> ```
>
> Or in the case of the Loop API:
>
> ```py
> optimize(..., generation_strategy=gs)
> ```
>
> Seems to work well for my use-case; thank you! I'll try to update the other relevant issues soon.